# Antialiased borders after rendering

Tags: render-settings, anime-studio

I'm doing an animation with Moho 12 Pro and i started animating two characters made of shapes from the software itself (without any import).

But when I render them, on the arms clearly there are some weird 'borders' (the arms itself are only lines with strokes) and even if I render the arms of the characters separately, the borders still persist.

If I uncheck 'antialiasing' those dissapear, but the output looks really jaggy and pixelated.

[image]

How can I fix this?

[image]

Edit: the first photo is with Antialiasing On, if i uncheck it, it looks worse.

Comment: Are you render them as PNG sequence or which format?

Comment: PNG sequence, i added another image with my configuration.